# Why is python generating an error when I attempt to log a list

Tags: python, logging

When I attempt to log a list inside a member function of a class, it stops the log file from being updated. I tried the following:

```
    def set_current_array(self, newvalue):
        print(f"newvalue={newvalue}") # works, prints   newvalue=[10]
        logging.info('Weight set_current_array %s', newvalue) # does not write to file, blocks all other logging
        logging.info(f'Weight set_current_array {newvalue}') # does not write to file, blocks all other logging
        self.current_array = newvalue
```

I have to remove both the logging.info lines before the log file will update (many other logging commands in the project).

Context:

- Python Version 3.9.1
- Windows 10

Comment: Have you tried converting the list to a string first before logging it?

Comment: I believe that has nothing to do with `lists` probably. Since, `logging.info(f'Weight set_current_array {newvalue}')` works if `newvalue` is a python list object

Comment: Try to remove the list from the logging and then see if the issue persists !?

Comment: @AmitPathak, yes as I said I commented out the lines and the logging works.

Comment: a new development: even adding `logging.info("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA")` inside th function blocks the logging process.

Comment: Yes, so the issue is not with the usage of the list in logging. Your implementation of it is correct. There is some issue with the logger that the function refers to ..

Comment: It sounds like wherever the logging is being sent to is the issue. That would be the thing to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by setting up the logging right at the beginning of the program:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='convert_st.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Started')

import all_other_packages
import...
...

def main:
   # main comes here
   ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(I also deleted the *.pyc files, don't know whether that has any relation).